# How to Convert RxJava (Observable) to Kotlin Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

I have a piece of countdown code on which I applied the Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe) operator and I want to convert it to Kotlin Flow. Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
if (countDownInterval < 0) {
            emitter.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("countDownInterval must be greater than or equal to 0"));
         }
         Task newTask = new Task(emitter);
         mTaskQueue.offer(newTask);
      }).doOnDispose(() -> {
         if (taskAtomicReference.get() != null) {
            taskAtomicReference.get().dispose();
         }
      });
   }

   private static class Task {
      ObservableEmitter<Long> mEmitter;

      Task(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Long> emitter) {
         mEmitter = emitter;
      }

      void dispose() {
         if (mEmitter != null) {
            mEmitter.onComplete();
            mEmitter = null;
```

Comment: public synchronized Observable<Long> countdown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
      AtomicReference<Task> taskAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();
      return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Long>) emitter -> {

Comment: Your code is in Java. Are you wanting to create a Kotlin Flow from a Java class?